# Svelte kit +page doesn't show updated Store value, shows default value instead

Tags: sveltekit, svelte-store

I've a problem with a store value not being displayed correctly on the page. When i update the store value i see a short flash with the new updated value ('updated') which then immediately reverts back to the default value ('default'). Logging the store (using 'tmp' var in +page) shows the value is actually updated. I also tried to disable SSR which eliminates the flashing but just shows the default value. I also tried update() instead of set() but no luck with that either.

```js
// store.ts
export const testStore = writable<string>('default')

// update store in another.ts file
testStore.set('updated')
```

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import {testStore} from '$lib/stores/test'
    import {get} from 'svelte/store'
    const tmp = get(testStore)
    console.log('tmp', tmp)
</script>

<form>
  <!-- after submitting this form testStore.set('updated') is called in another.ts -->
</form>

<p>$testStore: {$testStore}</p>
```

Edit: I may add that i have a form on the +page which i submit so the +page is reloaded which should explain why i see the store value flashing. But i have no idea why 'default' not 'updated' is shown on the page. The log() seems to work and shows 'updated'.

Answer (score 1):

Stores are just plain objects in memory, their state is *not* automatically persisted.

You should not try to use the same store on client and server (in form actions or the like), it will not refer to the same object as the server will run the code separately from any client.

When the client code loads it will have the default value again, overwriting the value rendered on the server.

There are many ways of storing values, e.g. in a DB or on the client in storages. You have to decide how to do that. If the value comes from the server, it should be sent from the [`load` function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load) and then (if necessary) put in a store on the client only.

Comment: Thanks @H.B. I'll use database in end anyway but just started playing with stores. I still wonder why console.log('tmp', tmp) is correctly showing 'updated'. Is the code block in +page running on the server side and the html part in the client? I'd like to see a block diagram or flow chart to understand it all better. I couldn't find useful infos in the docs about that.

Comment: The docs are a bit lacking in that regard, people have already opened issues about that and also requested something like diagrams. The code can get rendered on the server and on the client. For the first load the page is rendered on the server (this also runs the code) and hydrated on the client, for client navigation, it only loads the code/data to render the specific page and renders it on the client (any outer layouts do not change).

Comment: Thanks again. I'm looking forward to better Svelte documentation. Its really lacking at the moment making some concepts hard to understand, particularly for newbies. It also doesn't help that many tutorials and articles are now outdated. There should be a better system for marking outdated content on the web.